# Is there any good open source ASP.NET application using MVP pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvp

I'm trying to upgrade my existing web forms application to upcoming framework and rewriting couple of workflow as per the new business requirements.  I want to introduce TDD based development in this project but after some investigation found that ASP.NET MVC will not help me as my web existing application is using lots of Infragistics UltraWebGrid controls for grouping, paging, column moving etc and there is no good alternative grids in ASP.NET MVC world.  I also need to support blackberry in this release.  So, am planning to use both MVP for desktop client and MVC for blackberry client in same project.

I would like to know if someone has done something similar in their project and links to any good open source asp.net applicaton using MVP pattern.  I dont want to use WCSF as it is too heavy weight.  I saw their MVPBundle sample application but it lacks use of modern tools like IoC (Unity or StructureMap), Mocking framework etc.

Regards,
Sunil

Answer (score 2):

The [latest incarnation](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) of [Nerd Dinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/) has [mobile support](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx) in an ASP.NET MVC app.

I'm not sure about the JS support on a black-berry but there are quite a few grid/repeater type controls and mechanisms available using either jQuery or the forthcoming [ASP.NET AJAX 4](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=AJAX) templating controls.